# React Hooks: Refresh data on goBack()

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have two screens, A and B:

```
A -> B
```

B adds data, while A has a table with that data. When I add the data in `B`, I'm calling `goBack()` from the `useHistory()` react hook. However, `A` doesn't refresh when I added data to the database, as it shouldn't by default.

I only want `A` to refresh if I actually add something in `B`. How do I do this? How would I detect when `goBack()` is called in `A`, and only update if certain conditions are met?

Comment: Instead of trying to detect thing, why not embrace the declarative nature of React, and use something like Redux or another state management library? You can also utilize context yourself, as @apincik suggested, but why invent the wheel again...

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution, you can wrap your components to context - HOC. Or you can use something else intstead of goBack, push with params, simple HOC with state, pass props...

```
const DataContext = React.createContext(null);

// or pass props.children to DataContext.Provider, or props to A,B...
function DataApp() {
    const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);
    const toggleRefresh = () => { setRefresh(refresh => !refresh) };
    <DataContext.Provider value={{refresh, toggleRefresh}}>
        <A />
        <B />
    </DataContext.Provider>
}


function A() {
    const { refresh, toggleRefresh } = React.useContext(DataContext);
    useEffect(() => { /* Should be data refreshed? */ }, []);
}

function B() {
    const { refresh, toggleRefresh } = React.useContext(DataContext);
    const submitData = () => { toggleRefresh(); /* goBack() */ };
}
```